# Onsen/Wordpress Category link

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, categories, onsen-ui

Hi I'm new in onsen/wordpress development

I have categories on wordpress and call categories on onsen using:

```
<ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in menuItems track by $index" class="menu-item" ng-click="showCategory($index)">
```

to show all categories

but i want only to show specific categories how I can do that? What is the right code for ng-click?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I'm not sure I understood well because your request seems very simple. You can store in `menuItems` just the items you want to display. You can also use [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) if you just want to keep one variable.

Comment: You can also use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf).

Comment: acctually inside my .js i have this code 

    $scope.showCategory = function(index){
        
      $rootScope.categoryID = $scope.menuItems[index];
      $scope.menu.setMainPage('cat.html', {closeMenu: true});

    };

to print all my categories from wordpress to onsen app.

but i want instead to print all iwant to specific the links on categories

Comment: Sounds like this is a wordpress issue and not Onsen.  If you are wanting to limit the data returned, then you would need to post the Wordpress function calls you are using.  Can you edit your post with that information?